# Name change UK visitor visa application

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, premium-services

I'm filling out the form for a standard visitor visa for the UK, they have a question `Are you now or have you ever been known by another name?` I have changed my name years ago and all my documents have my new name and no mention of old names is anywhere. I'll still write my old name in that question as an honest applicant but my question is do we need to provide documentation for a name change for a UK visitor visa? Because I don't have any documentation regarding that.

Comment: Does the form ask you to provide documentation for the name change?

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Comment: Then I think you have your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do what the form asks you to do.**

If it doesn't ask for documentation, don't send any.

The point about asking for other names is so that they can track your previous activities by the name you were previously known. There would be no point to claiming that you had previously used a name when in reality you hadn't, so they really don't care whether you had legally changed your name.